# This code is supposed to understand a String as a list of Chars, but it doesn't

Tags: haskell

```
startswith:: Eq u => [u] -> [u] -> Bool
startswith [] _ = True
startswith _ [] = False
startswith (x:xs) (y:ys)
    |  x==y = startswith xs ys
    |  otherwise = False
```

if I enter startswith ['D','o'] ['D','o','g'] 
the program is happy and I get True
if I enter startswith [Do] [Dog] I get False, but shouldn't the two be equal?

Comment: `[Do]` and `[Dog]` are neither strings nor lists of characters. Unless you happen to have constructors named `Do` and `Dog` in scope, they are just invalid expressions. String literals are given using `"` (as in most languages), e.g., `"Do"` and `"Dog"`. `['D','o']` and `"Do"` are two different spellings of the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `[Do]` and `[Dog]` are not strings. If you happen to have a data-type with constructors `Do` and `Dog`, then they will be lists of that data-type. Otherwise it does not make any sense. You want to do `startswith "Do" "Dog"`

Comment: They dont have to be the same type, but for the function to typecheck, then they do. I see your point.